# Changing font with Javascript being superseded

Tags: javascript

I am sure this is a very simple problem but I am trying to change the font of a div box with a javascript program. I have managed to do this but then when implementing this in my full site it is superseded by the font set in my .body css

I've tried a few solutions to no avail

```
    <p><input id="sampleFont1" placeholder="Top text..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="Totext"></p>
    <p><input id="sampleFont2" placeholder="Bottom text..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="Bottotext"></p>

      <select name="Font" onchange="myFunction(this);" size="5" style="height: 500px;">
        <option>Georgia</option>
        <option>Palatino Linotype</option>
        <option>Book Antiqua</option>
        <option>Times New Roman</option>
        <option>Arial</option>
        <option>Helvetica</option>
        <option>Arial Black</option>
        <option>Impact</option>
        <option>Lucida Sans Unicode</option>
        <option>Tahoma</option>
        <option>Verdana</option>
        <option>Courier New</option>
        <option>Lucida Console</option>
      </select>

      <script type="text/javascript">

        function myFunction(selectTag) {
        var listValue = selectTag.options[selectTag.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("sampleFont1").style.fontFamily = listValue;
        document.getElementById("sampleFont2").style.fontFamily = listValue;
      }

      </script>
```

In this example, it does change the font but when I attach it to my full site the font change is superseded.

Comment: Please post your `body.css` that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Eg: In CSS `font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;`

In JS: `document.getElementById("demo").style.setProperty("font-family", "Times New Roman", "important");`

Use [CSS !important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules) to overide body css

Comment: How would I do this through the Javascript?

Comment: [link](https://dreamweddingfavours.com/product/wedding-favour/) This is the site, you can probably see what I am trying to do. After inputting text and selecting the font it isn't changing